# first() and take() do not work correctly in Eager Load laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Post Model that have a **hasMany** relation to **post_pics** and belongsToMany relation to **Category** Model.

I want to fetch All Posts and All their Categories but First post_pics of each Post.

For that I write this Eager Load Constraints :

```
Post::with([
                'post_pics'  => function ($query) {
                    $query->select(['pic_id', 'pic_name', 'post_id'])->first()->get();
                },
                'categories' => function ($query) {
                    $query->select(['categories.cat_id', 'name']);
                }
            ])
                ->take(12)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->get(['post_id', 'post_title', 'post_alias', 'post_content', 'comments_count', 'created_at']);

        return $latestPosts;
```

When I remove **first()** method after **select()** method all things works and returns  all pictures of each Post but when I use **first()** method, only returns first picture of Models that have more than one picture.

I try to **take(1)** Constraints but it does not work too.

What is Problem and How Can I do that?

Comment: remove your `get()` and have only `first()`

Comment: I try it , but it does not work again. return null array for Post Model that have only on postPic in database.

Comment: Are you sure that you have enough coloumns that matches your query ?

Comment: postPic model have only `'pic_id', 'pic_name', 'post_id'` columns and I need to `'categories.cat_id', 'name'` columns of Category model and fetch only `'post_id', 'post_title', 'post_alias', 'post_content', 'comments_count', 'created_at'` columns on Post Model that because I do not need to reset of columns

Comment: Can you print your query using QueryLog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer in Laracasts Forum:

https://www.laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/first-and-take-do-not-work-correctly-in-eager-load-laravel